# RAC'ing property to be set

Tags: reactive-cocoa

Is it possible to observe a property of an object that is yet to be set?

I am trying to implement MVVM pattern and here's what I've got so far:

In my view controller I instantiate view model and model:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  Model * model = [Model initWithSomeData:[self dataFromSomewhere]];
  ViewModel * viewModel = [[ViewModel alloc] init];
  viewModel.model = model;

  RAC(self.propertyLabel, text) = [RACObserve(self.viewModel, someTransformedProperty];
}
```

Now in ViewModel class I have following code in initialiser

```
- (instancetype)init
{
  self = [super init];

  if (self) {
    RAC(self, someTransformedProperty = [RACObserve(self.model, plainProperty) map:id^(id value) {
      return [self transformProperty:value];
    }];
  }
}
```

Now the problem is that property label does not get set. Is there any way around this? Also - if `plainProperty` in `model` is nil I get a crash even if I provide `nilValue` as 3rd parameter to `RAC` macro.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah! Just turn `RACObserve(self.model, plainProperty)` into `RACObserve(self, model.plainProperty)`.

Oh but also:

```
ViewModel * viewModel = [[ViewModel alloc] init];
viewModel.model = model;
self.viewModel = viewModel; // <--- don't forget that
RAC(self.propertyLabel, text) = RACObserve(self.viewModel, someTransformedProperty);
```

As far as the crash goes, hard to say what that could be without more info. Is `transformProperty:` crashing on `nil`?

Comment: The crash was the issue of `map:` block (I tried to initialise attributed string with nil).